# Flexbox columns multiple children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using flex-boxes and only four `div`s inside the container…
I cannot handle it…

I was stack on it…

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.x-1 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.x-2 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.x-3 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.x-4 {
  background: red;
  height: 700px;
  width: 800;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="x-1"></div>
  <div class="x-2"></div>
  <div class="x-3"></div>
  <div class="x-4"></div>
</div>
```

#### EDIT

I'll start from the beginning. I would like to get the same effect as in the image. I insert the code below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 100px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box-1 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.box-2 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.box-3 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.box-4 {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to give the flex container a height so only the 3 yellow fit, then the 4th will wrap...oh, and remove _nowrap_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten styles to achieve adaptivity, flexibility and maintainability:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* taking margins into account, so 90px */
  padding: 0 90px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3,
.box-4 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box-4 {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  height: 800px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  
  .left {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .box-1,
  .box-2 {
    width: auto;
    flex: 1 0 0;
  }
  
  .box-3 {
    width: auto;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  
  .left {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
    
  .box-1,
  .box-2,
  .box-3,
  .box-4 {
    width: auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-4"></div>
</div>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8u7ppxd/7/) to test resizing.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the yellow boxes in their own container...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left div[class^='x'] {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.x-4 {
  background: red;
  height: 700px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="x-1"></div>
    <div class="x-2"></div>
    <div class="x-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="x-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to have divs to your code

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.x-1 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.x-2 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.x-3 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.x-4 {
  background: red;
  height: 700px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
          <div class="x-1"></div>
          <div class="x-2"></div>
          <div class="x-3"></div>
     </div>
     <div>
          <div class="x-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Grid layout here. Here is demo, I removed redundant `.left` block and rewrited styles. This will work even in IE10+:

```css
.container {
  /* taking margins into account, so 90px */
  padding: 0 90px;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  /* taking margins into account, so 220px */
  -ms-grid-columns: 220px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 220px 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3,
.box-4 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}

.box-2 {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.box-3 {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.box-4 {
  background: red;
  height: 800px;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto;
  }
  
  .box-1 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  
  .box-2 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  
  .box-3 {
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }
  
  .box-4 {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto auto;
  }
  
  .box-1,
  .box-2,
  .box-3,
  .box-4 {
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  }
  
  .box-1 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  
  .box-2 {
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
  }
  
  .box-3 {
    -ms-grid-row: 4;
    grid-row: 4;
  }
  
  .box-4 {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
  <div class="box-3"></div>
  <div class="box-4"></div>
</div>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8u7ppxd/6/) to test resizing.